# Ввод ФИО и вывод фамилии через JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Подскажите, как можно реализовать следующую структуру (js/json):

- Происходит ввод фамилии
- при нажатии на кнопку получить выводится только фамилия

не совсем понимаю, как с помощью формы (html, js,json) это реализовать.
По логике необходимо заполнить массив и из него методом json вывести значение, но не совсем могу понять как это сделать.

буду рад если поможете разобраться.

Comment: Не понятно, что вы хотите сделать и как это должно работать. Ввод фамилии(куда?) еще как то понятно, но вот причем тут json и массив - не ясно совсем.